# Type 'typeof Sequelize' is missing the following properties from type 'Sequelize': Sequelize, config, modelManager, connectionManager, and 23 more

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to use `sequelize` v5 with TypeScript. When using commonjs, `sequelize` organizes the models like this:

`models/index.js`:

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

// ...

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

So I want to do the same thing using TypeScript.

`models/index.ts`:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { DbInterface } from '../../@types';

export const createModels = (sequelizeConfig: any): DbInterface => {
  const { database, username, password, params } = sequelizeConfig;
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, params);

  const db: DbInterface = {
    sequelize,
    Sequelize, // <= TSC throw an error here.
  };

  Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });

  return db;
};
```

`@types/dbInterface.ts`:

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export interface DbInterface {
  sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize;
  Sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize;
}
```

TSC throw a type error:

> Type 'typeof Sequelize' is missing the following properties from type 'Sequelize': Sequelize, config, modelManager, connectionManager, and 23 more.

How can I make the type correctly?

Package version:

```
"sequelize": "^5.21.3"
"typescript": "^3.7.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a problem using [sequelize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript)?
It has all the definitions you need and therefore you don't need to write your own.

If you have a problem using [sequelize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) just install [@types/sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sequelize) to get these types.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to switch to using another node module for now.

Comment: Install @types/sequelize as a dev dependency: `npm install --save-dev`. It is only type declarations - it basically exports everything you are trying to do.

Comment: sequelize v5 and v6 ship with their own types, and you do not use @types/sequelize anymore

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize v5 and v6, importing `Sequelize` will import the namespace, not types. What you want is to `import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize'` (note the braces around `Sequelize`) instead.

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize'

interface DbInterface {
  sequelize: Sequelize
  Sequelize: Sequelize
}

declare const db: DbInterface
db.sequelize // exists
db.Sequelize //exists
```

Or, alternatively

```js
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'

interface DbInterface {
  sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize
  Sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize
}
```